# How do I create a minimal complete verifiable example?

Tags: support, minimal-reproducible-example, faq-proposed

I asked a question, and it was closed with the following reason.

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

I don't understand how to do this. Can you please give me some examples?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

Comment: Related and helpful: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 14):

The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) should make it fairly clear what a minimal, complete, verifiable example is

- ## Minimal

  means remove any code/html/css that is not relevant to the issue.
- ## Complete

  post all the relevant code and any other information needed to reproduce the issue. Is it only a specific browser? Specific Machines? OS Versions?
- ## Verifiable

  verify your example with the info you supplied actually reproduces the problem.

## Example [Bad] Questions:

- ### Linking to a fiddle only: ** [**BAD**] **!

  > My program doesn't work. Why?
  >
  > [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/ma259qp2/)

  You're required to put the code **in the question itself**. [Use a snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).
- ### Linking to some offsite place: ** [**BAD**] **!

  > My program doesn't work, why?
  >
  > See my program here: https://greggman.github.io/foobar/index.html

  You're required to put the code **in the question itself**. You should
  also mention what you tried.
- ### Not making a *Minimal* example: ** [**BAD**] **!

  > My program doesn't work, here's the code
  >
  > ```
  > const foo = 123;
  > const bar = 456;
  >
  > ...300 more lines of code...
  > ```

  300 lines of code is probably not a **minimal example**.
- ### Using a giant dataURL: ** [**BAD**] **!

  > My program doesn't work,
  >
  > ```
  > ...
  > img.src = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K... 20k of data ...
  > ```

  If you need an image consider using a canvas to create a small image.
  If you have to use an image to show the issue make a small image like
  8x8 pixels, run it through [pngcrush](http://pngcrush.com/) to remove
  all unneeded data. If you need a big image upload your image to imgur
  and reference it from there. Be sure to use an `https` URL and set
  `img.crossOrigin = "anonymous"`
- ### Using giant data of any kind: ** [**BAD**] **!

  > My program trying to draw 1000 billboards doesn't work,
  >
  > ```
  > var vertices = [
  >   0.12324323493434, 0.123245299999, 120.32342535, 
  >   0.4323493434, 0.23245233223, -930.32342788, 
  >   ...4000... more vertices ..
  > ```

  Make a *minimal* example. Do you need 1000 billboards to show the issue or can you show the issue with just 1, 2, or 3 billboards? Use as little data as needed to show the issue.
  Truncate the data, `0.12` vs `0.12394393958348` etc..
- ### Including lots of unneeded HTML or CSS: ** [**BAD**] **!

  > My program doesn't work, Why?
  >
  > ```
  > <html>
  >   <head>
  >     <title>My program</title>
  >     <style>
  >     ...10-100 lines of CSS...
  >     </style>
  >
  > ...etc...
  > ```

  `<html>`, `<head>`, `<title>` are generally not needed. They
  certainly are not needed in a snippet. Also unless your question
  is about CSS specifically don't waste space with a huge amount
  of CSS irrelevant to reproducing your issue. Again, make a
  **minimal** example.
- ### Linking to resources likely to disappear: ** [**BAD**] **!

  > My program doesn't work, Why?
  >
  > ```
  > <script src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/hhkulq8sgj8lm12/shared.js?dl=0"></script>
  > <script src="https://myschool.edu/myuserdir/jquery.min.js"></script>
  > <script>
  >
  >   ...
  > ```

  Stack Overflow is not meant for fixing your personal bugs. It's meant for
  sharing solutions. The moment you take down your dropbox or you
  update your script on your server the code in your question will
  no longer work and the question will become irrelevant.

  Instead if it's a common library link to a CDN. Ideally a versioned
  CDN. Example [here are links to specific versions of Jquery](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/)
  as well as [many other libraries](https://cdnjs.com/libraries).

  As for the link to your personal server or company server, copy
  that code into the question. Just make sure you pare it down to
  the **minimal** number of functions needed to reproduce the error.
  In other words if you're using a library with 100 functions but
  you only need 3 of those functions to get your example to run
  then only put those 3 functions in your question

## [Bad] Example

> Why does my cube spin a bunch when I move the speed slider?

```js
let speed = 1;

// Setup
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector("#canvas")});

// Make and setup a camera.
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 1, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

// Make a scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Make a cube.
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);

// Make a material
const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  ambient: 0x555555,
  color: 0x555555,
  specular: 0xffffff,
  shininess: 50,
  shading: THREE.SmoothShading
});

// Create a mesh based on the geometry and material
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

// Add 2 lights.
const light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xff0040, 2, 0);
light1.position.set(200, 100, 300);
scene.add(light1);

const light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0x0040ff, 2, 0);
light2.position.set(-200, 100, 300);
scene.add(light2);

function resize() {
  var width = renderer.domElement.clientWidth;
  var height = renderer.domElement.clientHeight;
  if (renderer.domElement.width !== width || renderer.domElement.height !== height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

function animate(time) {
  time *= .001;
  
  resize();
  mesh.rotation.x = time * speed;
  mesh.rotation.y = time * speed * .5;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

document.querySelector("#speed").addEventListener('input', e => {
  speed = e.target.value / 100;
});
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: red;
  background-color: white;
}
.content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  z-index: 2;
  text-shadow: 
     1px 1px 0px white, 
     -1px 1px 0px white, 
     1px -1px 0px white, 
     -1px -1px 0px white;
}
#ui {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My example</title>
    <script src="https://greggman.github.io/doodles/js/three.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My example program</h1>
    <div class="content">
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
      <div id="ui">
        <div>speed: <input id="speed" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="20" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Problems with the above example:

- It's including a script from some random location instead of a CDN so it's likely not to work once the script disappears or is updated.
- It's got tons of un-needed HTML
- It's got tons of un-needed CSS
- It's got plenty of code unrelated to the issue

## Better example

> Why does my cube spin a bunch when I move the speed slider?

```js
let speed = 1;

// Setup
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: document.querySelector("#canvas")});

// Make and setup a camera.
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, 2, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 400;

// Make a scene
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

// Make a cube.
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);

// Make a material
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  wireframe: true,
  color: 0xFF0000,
});

// Create a mesh based on the geometry and material
const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

function animate(time) {
  time *= .001;
  
  mesh.rotation.x = time * speed;
  mesh.rotation.y = time * speed * .5;

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

document.querySelector("#speed").addEventListener('input', e => {
  speed = e.target.value / 100;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/85/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<div>speed: <input id="speed" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="20" />
```

Why is this version better?

- It's using a CDN for the library which is unlikely to disappear
- The irrelevant HTML has been removed
- The irrelevant CSS has been removed
- Being able to resize the canvas was not important so that code has been removed.
- Using a simpler material means less parameters are needed and no lights had to be setup so more code irrelevant to the issue has been removed.