# If this is not minimal, what's minimal?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, minimal-reproducible-example

It took me a lot of effort and energy to break down a multi threaded TLS application into a single threaded minimal application.

I made sure that any one can build and run my minimal example without any frustrations. I included build instructions for this minimal application including the TLS library itself. I included the stack traces in addition to that.

I've located the line which is causing the bug but I can't wrap my mind around how to go ahead and fix it, so I asked the question.

I started a bounty today since the question didn't get answered.

Today, a user commented on the question that,

> This question is a dump of your whole program followed by instructions
> on how to build and run your program followed by "please debug my
> application". You should create a minimal reproducible example
> emphasis on minimum.

What's minimal then?

For reference, here is the question and that comment: [*Segmentation fault when using a shared_ptr for private_key*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66068134/segmentation-fault-when-using-a-shared-ptr-for-private-key?noredirect=1#comment116877826_66068134)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; a very lengthy conversation with 30+ messages has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228445/discussion-on-question-by-jeffbrtc-if-this-is-not-minimal-whats-minimal). **If you have an opinion or perspective to share that is relevant to this situation, please post an answer.**

Comment: This post, and the post that it references, are perfect examples of why the comment/chat system needs to be reformed.  The last thing that moderators should be spending time on is shuffling comments around from one place to another.

Comment: Minimal doesn't equal small. Sometimes people forget that. Although the std::cout output at the end could probably go as well.

Comment: @CodyGray Comments are not for extended discussion **on standard sites**. Meta sites *are implicitly about discussing things*. How does one discuss a question or answer except in its comments? Nobody uses chat for this because it's divorced from the subject at hand.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm sure SE Inc. will get to fixing that any day now... once they're done with all the unnecessarily superfluous things, like [rewriting perfectly working post editors for no apparent reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor).

Comment: One thing I notice is that listing specific language versions, like [c++11] makes these situations more likely. People have favorite tags and expect the questions to be _about_ c++11, as opposed to merely happening with c++11 code. I get more success, in my question by listing just [c++], unless it very specifically relates to c++11.

Comment: Meta relaxes the rules slightly, @IanKemp; I grant a lot of leeway for people to have relevant discussions in comment chains on Meta posts, but >30 messages is just unwieldy, on Meta sites or not. Furthermore, *most* these comments shouldn't have been posted as comments in the first place, as they were attempting to answer the question. My proposed solution is not for people to move the discussion to chat, but rather to *post an answer*, which is why I stated as such (and bolded it) in my initial comment.

Comment: @Trilarion Minimal doesn't necessarily equal minimum either. Minimum is the fact. Minimal is the vibe.

Comment: @0-1 Minimal or minimum, it must contain the problem and leave out everything else. Of all the things on SO I think this is one of the clearest concepts. For example: what does "useful" mean when voting...

Comment: I must admit the question and answer has been upvoted way too much for what they are worth. Also this meta question is questionable at best

Comment: @00110001 This question does not show any research. Surely this topic came up before and possibly not only once.

Comment: @Trilarion Well, I've already done a research into minimal stuff and was confused by that comment hence the question. Let the votes to speak itself.

Comment: I'm never seen such a meta-effect war on the linked question, which right now scores a +56 vs. -20 votes. Though smaller, also the answer is a votes battlefield.

Comment: @jeffbRTC "I've already done a research into minimal stuff" Please show it. I think that with a few links the matter would become clearer. If I have time, I can also do it.

Comment: @Trilarion Which specific part unclear for you on this question?

Comment: Sorry. I meant clear in the sense of the solution becoming more obvious. I think that if one takes into account what others have written about minimal examples, a single comment by a single user gets less weight and it becomes clear that comments in general are low weight on this platform. Your question part "what's minimal" has likely been answered in the last 10 years somewhere.

Comment: @Trilarion But this question is tagged as "specific-question" so I don't see any scandal in OP asking for a specific answer..

Comment: There is [How do I create a minimal complete verifiable example?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349789/how-do-i-create-a-minimal-complete-verifiable-example) and of course there is the help page associated with minimal examples [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). At least the help page would be the authoritative source. Don't get me wrong. The question on SO is a nice example of a complex minimal example and the commenter was wrong, I think.

Comment: So you have about 100 lines of code, and deleting **any part** of it causes it to not crash?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Firstly, everybody here is a human, and humans make mistakes. It happens that I retract my close votes after a second glance, and there are most likely close votes that I should retract (or not cast in the first place) that I don’t. Sometimes we’re simply too quick and judge a question from a general pattern. And sometimes multiple people are too quick and the question gets closed. It’s bad, but it happens. And it’s also unavoidable, because people moderating and curating this site cannot be expected to spend 10-15 minutes of thinking for every close vote.

> **Clarification of above paragraph.**
>
> I don't mean that it's a good thing to close vote when you're unsure. I'm just stating the fact that it's done like that very often. If your post have "the general look" of a bad post, it's likely to get close voted. And it's also a fact that very many posts CAN be fairly judged in a matter of a few seconds. But of course, mistakes will always be done.

If you have created a MRE, but the question still looks messy, it can be a good idea to include a line like *“I read about creating an MRE, and this is the shortest I have been able to come up with.”* because that’s a very good sign that it might be a question worth spending some more time on. However, if it’s obvious that you just pasted that line without actually trying to minimize the code, then you will probably get a cascade of downvotes.

I don’t know when you got that comment, but I can see that you reduced the amount of code considerably at some stage. That’s a very good thing. But it also emphasizes that your code was not minimal when you posted it.

Cody Gray gave a good answer here, so I’ll answer in a more general way. Here are some things about this concept of minimal reproducible example:

- Identify the function that produces the wrong result. If the input to that function is produced by other functions and code, hard code the result from that function. So if you have `foo(bar())`, change to `int r = bar(); foo(r)`, use a debugger, printout or whatever method you like to find the value of `r`, maybe 42, and then do `foo(42)`.
- The above is especially good when the input value depends on user input or files. Instead of *”This produces the wrong value when I enter 42: `scanf(“%d”, &r); foo(r)`”*  just do *”This produces the wrong value for 42: `foo(42)`”*
- Sometimes when you use these techniques, you may be surprised. For instance, if you enter `hello` as input to `fgets(buffer, size, stdin); foo(buffer);` you might not get the same result as `foo("hello")`. Any seasoned C coder can instantly see the problem here, but the bottom line is that the problem is not in `foo()`, but instead in lack of understanding of how the library function `fgets()` work.
- You’re required to debug your code as much as possible before posting here, and creating a MRE is actually an **excellent** debugging method. So by not providing a MRE, you’re showing that you have not done enough to solve your problem. Possibly because you lack the knowledge that this is a good debugging method. No matter the reason, the solution is the same. Create a MRE.

Comment: +1 for that last part on creating a MRE. I see so many users posting irrelevant parts of their code that only makes it harder for us to focus on the real problems!

Comment: I'm uncomfortable with your first paragraph. Of course, we all make mistakes, but at the same time, there is no quota of close votes you need to cast. If it takes 10-15 minutes to decide whether to cast a vote, and you don't have the time, just move on to another post. "There's no shame in pressing Skip" is the advice given to reviewers who get it wrong, and I think the same advice applies here.

Comment: @cigien perhaps that it is the advice, and we would defnitely prefer users to invest more time in understanding each post in the review queue (which I personally do), but unforetunately the reality is that most of us *don't*

Comment: @ΛRYΛN If you're talking about the review queues, I don't really mind how long you spend on each question there. There are mechanisms in place if you get too many things wrong. I'm assuming the klutt is talking about closing posts outside the review queue, where there is really no penalty at all for getting things wrong, and hence my advice to consider skipping more often.

Comment: @klutt The library has it own functions to manage memory. it doesn't use malloc thus debugger unable to keep track of it.

Comment: @cigien That paragraph is not intended primarily to validate that kind of reviewing, but more to explain that that's how it is done by many users.

Comment: "use a debugger to find the value of r" - or just print/log it. Many users asking questions here, especially the ones who need help creating a minimal example, don't know how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 71):

Your question has never been closed. There was never any compelling reason to take action.

Whenever you see a comment suggesting how to improve one of your posts that you disagree with, feel free to ignore it. In this case, if you had already worked to make your example as minimal as possible, then that would have been a good reason to simply ignore a comment stating otherwise. (Another good strategy—and the one you took—is to dispute the premise, asking the commentator if they can provide any more specific advice on what to remove. If that doesn't lead anywhere productive, then just bow out and go back to ignoring the comment.)

I've now deleted the whole discussion that arose from that comment, as it's no longer applicable (the question was never closed as a result, and it has now been answered).

The term "minimal" is inherently subjective, and merely reflects the fact that **we want you to take proactive steps to reduce the amount of code posted in the question**. In other words, we want you to put forth some effort to debug the problem yourself, removing and simplifying irrelevant portions. We don't want you to just dump your whole application, with hundreds or thousands of lines of code, into the question. If you've done that, and slimmed it down as much as you think is feasible, then that is sufficient.

As far as the "rules" go, like I said above, "minimal" is inherently subjective, so someone is going to have to make the judgment call. The first person to make that judgment call is always you, the asker. The second group of people are the users with [close-vote privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), who have the ability to close a question if they do not feel that the example is sufficiently "minimal" (requires a "consensus" of 3 votes). A third group of people can override the judgment of this first group, *reopening* the question if they feel that the example was sufficiently minimal. And, of course, [diamond moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) and this Meta site are your final avenue of escalation, if you disagree with the closure of a question. Some might see it as unfortunate that we cannot and do not try to define "minimal" any more concretely than this, leaving it open to the judgment of the community. But honestly, I think this is the best system in the long run, as it puts the judgment into the hands of the community (and hopefully subject-matter experts), rather than trying to dictate a one-size-fits-all policy from "on high".

Note further that we don't just ask for you to create a minimal example because we're a bunch of trolls. We aren't even doing it for purely selfish reasons. Creating a minimal example *substantially* lowers the barrier to entry when it comes to answering the question, so putting in this work substantially increases the odds of you getting good answers. It takes a lot more time commitment on the part of prospective answerers to do the debugging/reduction themselves, which reduces the number of people who are willing to try, as well as reducing the likelihood of a successful outcome. This is why the guideline has been introduced to this Q&A site. Adding a bounty to the question becomes more necessary when there is more "work" to be done by prospective answerers. While we don't want bounties to become end-arounds for our rules about what determines a good question, it is less likely that you would have needed to set a bounty if you had presented a sufficiently simple question. Of course, sometimes that is not possible. This may be one of those cases. I haven't studied it in detail. Because…as I mentioned, people have limited amounts of time to devote. :-)

Comment: Good post but I would argue that "minimal" is objective, but "minimal *enough*" is subjective.

Comment: So... you want to argue about the definition of a word that I said is "inherently subjective"? Why am I not surprised? ;-)

Comment: @CodyGray please note that "minimal" example that OP started this thread about was cut down to almost 1/3 of its original size to be what is there now... This may be good thing to note in the answer as size of the sample now merit no "your minimal is way to big" discussion...

Comment: @CodyGray I would argue that the word that is inherently subjective is not the word "minimal". I'ts the word "enough".

Comment: "Whenever you see a comment suggesting how to improve one of your posts that you disagree with, feel free to ignore it" - I don't entirely agree with this sentiment. It's true that not all comments need to be acted upon, nor even make much sense at all, but I would recommend always trying to see the point of view of a commenter, considering what the upvotes and downvotes tell you and considering what other posts look like (and indeed whether it's closed or has close votes). Only dismiss/ignore it if none or few of those lead you to conclude that it might be reasonable.

Comment: Further to the final paragraph - in the quest to minimise the code required to reproduce the problem, often the answer will be found. At this point you can either avoid the need to ask the question in the first place or, if you're feeling more generous, create the question anyway then answer it yourself if you feel that somebody else is likely to have that issue as well.

Comment: "Whenever you see a comment suggesting how to improve one of your posts that you disagree with, feel free to ignore it." - Hmm, I wonder if it was about disagreeing. I think it was about being afraid of having a default tag printed on the head as "one of those low quality posters who just dump their entire code". I know I would have involved the community to know how to do better in their shoes.

Comment: Another advantage of forcing people to create a minimal repro is that in doing that, they often find new insights.  I have 4k rep, but have never asked a question.  The few times that I've started to go done that path, about an hour or so into preparing the question, I've found my answer.  For me, preparing a [mcve] is a bit of an extended rubber-duck debugging session.

Answer (score 33):

**I am the one that posted that comment.**

For reference my comment was somewhere after [the bounty was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66068134/3) and before [edit 5](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66068134/5) (to the best of my recollection). This puts my comment before [edit 7](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66068134/7) where you removed a lot of code.

I will explain why I posted that comment and I hope you will understand my reasonings or at least see where I come from.

### General rant

Out of all the reasons for which a questions is considered of low quality on this site I am personally most frustrated by posts that do not make the effort to trim down unnecessary code. Most kinds of bad questions I mostly ignore: questions of the like "please gimme the codes" are unsalvageable; question of simple basic matters will get answers from someone else or they will eventually find the answer in their text books; and so on.

(Debugging) Questions asking help about a real problem for which the OP is unlikely to find the answers in a book on their own interest me because I believe I can be of help. However when I see a big code dump with lots of lines of code that are completely irrelevant to the issue at hand frustrates me because I could help, but the OP didn't do what is in their power to enable me to help them. I don't have the time and the mental energy to swift thought previously unseen code to find that 1 issue in a sea of completely unrelated things that happen in the code: input read, full classes with full data members, constructors and methods, operator overloads, all sorts of unrelated functions, full bodies of functions etc.

I am willing to invest time in finding the problem if what I do in that time the OP couldn't have done it himself/herself. Removing unrelated code, translating id names, making a MRE is something that the OP could do. I know that most OPs don't do that not because of malice but because they don't know how and it frustrates me because it's something so simple that everyone could do that is a barrier for my investment in their problem.

For a concrete, clear example, a recent C++ [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000593/i-am-getting-error-c2678-binary-no-operator-found-which-takes-a-lef-hand) (deleted now, you need privilege to see it) was like this: the OP identified that the error is "no operator== found" for his class when he defined such an operator. The initial post contained  250 lines of code. I vote to close, post a comment about needed a MRE. After this the OP clearly tried to create a MRE. A few edits followed, each followed by my comment along the lines "still not minimal". This is what the OP finally managed to minimize to:

> Tile.h:
>
> ```
> #pragma once
> #ifndef TILE_H
> #define TILE_H
> #include "GameObject.h"
> #include "GL\glut.h"
> #include <iostream>
> class Tile : public GameObject
> {
>
> public:
>     Tile();
>     Tile(float, float, bool, bool);
>     int i;
>     int j;
>     Tile* parent;
>     bool operator==(const Tile& other) const;
>     bool operator!=(const Tile& other) const;
> };
>
> #endif
> ```
>
> Tile.cpp:
>
> ```
> Tile::Tile() : GameObject() { }
>
> Tile::Tile(float x, float y, bool active, bool blocked) 
> {
>     this->x = x;
>     this->y = y;
>     this->active = active;
>     this->blocked = blocked;
>     parent = NULL;
> }
>
> bool Tile::operator==(const Tile& rhs) const
> {
>     return this->i == rhs.i && this->j == rhs.j;
> }
>
> bool Tile::operator!=(const Tile& rhs) const
> {
>     return this->i != rhs.i && this->j != rhs.j;
> }
> ```
>
> I have these two operators that are used to compare the two tiles with
> the '==' operator and the '!=' operator.
>
> Enemy.h:
>
> ```
> #pragma once
>     #ifndef ENEMY_H
>     #define ENEMY_H
>     #include "GameObject.h"
>     #include "Tile.h"
>     #include "Math.h"
>     #include <vector>
>     
>     class Enemy : public GameObject
>     {
>         Enemy();
>         Enemy(float, float, float, bool);
> void MoveTowards(Tile, Tile*, std::vector<std::vector<Tile>>, int, int);
>     std::vector<Tile> *openList;
>     std::vector<Tile> *closedList;
> std::vector<Tile>* AdjacentTiles(std::vector<std::vector<Tile>>, int, int);
>     };
>     #endif
> ```
>
> Enemy.cpp:
>
> ```
> Enemy::Enemy()  { }
> Enemy::Enemy(float x, float y, float radius, bool active) 
> {
>     this->x = x;
>     this->y = y;
>     this->radius = radius;
>     this->active = active;
> }
>
> void Enemy::MoveTowards(Tile currentTile, Tile* target, std::vector<std::vector<Tile>> worldTiles, int currentX, int currentY)
> {
>     
>
> Tile *currentStep = &this->openList->at(0);
> std::vector<Tile> *adjTiles = AdjacentTiles(worldTiles, currentStep->i, currentStep->j);
>
> Tile* step = &adjTiles->at(0);
>             
>             if (std::find(closedList->begin(), closedList->end(), step) != closedList->end())
>             {
>                 //continue;
>             }
>
>
>
>  if (std::find(openList->begin(), openList->end(), step) != openList->end())
>             {
>                 std::vector<Tile>::iterator it = std::find(this->openList->begin(), this->openList->end(), step);
>                 int index = std::distance(this->openList->begin(), it);
>                 step = &this->openList->at(index);
>             }
>
> }
> ```

This is 105 LOC. Clearly an improvement from the original 250 LOC. Getting over the fact that it isn't compilable, the main issue is that is still contains a lot of distraction code that only adds to the mental strain when trying to analyze the code. I am sure the OP thought this is as minimal as he could get. But: is inheritance pertinent to the issue at hand? Are all the data members? Are the constructors? And so on.

Seeing how the OP is genuinely trying I went on, looked over his code, created a MRE and gave him the link to it. This is a proper MRE of the issue:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class Tile
{
public:
    bool operator==(const Tile& other) const;
    bool operator!=(const Tile& other) const;
};

class Enemy
{
    std::vector<Tile>* closedList;

    void MoveTowards()
    {
        Tile* step {};

        std::find(closedList->begin(), closedList->end(), step);
    }
};
```

If you stuck through this long post **this here is the the main point of my answer**: please look at the proper MRE and then look at the OP code. See how much easier is to analyze the MRE vs the OP's code. Me and all of us here have to look over a stranger's code without any previous knowledge of the problem and context of the code presented. See how easy is to look over a proper MRE and how much mental strain analyzing the other one involves. And now think about the original 250 LOC code. It's a previously unseen code that we would have to go through and for each and every think that happens we would need to see if it's relevant or not and if not how we can remove it without affecting the result (the error the OP is getting). All all of that is something that the OP, the one who asks for our volunteer help could have done and should have done.

### Now back to your question

I hope that now you can see or even understand how when I came across your post what I saw were 250 LOC (coincidence, that is the same amount of LOCs as the original question in my example) with code that did all sorts of things:

- it stored encoded and decoded data
- it contained methods to emit and receive data
- it handled alerts from the server
- it handled sessions
- it stored all sorts of auth data (certificates, keys, stores)
- had all sorts of functions that were dealing with authorization and certifications
- creates certificates and private keys
- generates certificates and signs them
- reads a file from local storage
- creates a session
- connects to a server
- creates a certificate
- receives data

And on top of that we would need to install a library on our machine and start debugging your application. At that time there was no indication to me that you created this from a much larger multithreaded application. This was too much for me so I posted that comment immediately and I would have voted to close but the bounty prevented me.

With [edit 7](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66068134/7) you showed that your code was not minimal. You were able to reduce your code substantially to only 80 LOC (ignoring includes) code that visibly does less "things".

My "dump of your whole program" and "please debug my application" remarks were harsh and undeserving. I apologize for making them and for assuming you didn't do any substantial effort before posting. I also want to thank you for this meta posts as for me it serves as yet another reminder that for all those lazy questions there are also people genuinely doing their best. I should not have forgotten that.

Comment: I posted so much code because I didn't know what to delete and what is actually causing this. Maybe I didn't focus too much, but of course after your comment.

Comment: @bolov Thank you for a great answer! This can serve as a FAQ/howto on how to create an MRE, on how to debug your code, and on what to do before you ask for help on forums (or elsewhere). The answer also underlines yet again the genuine desire to help on behalf of the people who answer questions on SO, and how the OPs can make their life easier (e.g., by working hard on creating an MRE). The apology and thanks at the end of the answer are also great. I wish more meta posts ended up like that!

Comment: I agree with you 100%... the problem generally is that if the OPs of the world were able to do what you did and boil everything down to an actual MRE, they probably wouldn't have needed to ask the question in the first place. That's the conundrum. But like you, they need to show that they at least tried... but that's my biggest complaint/frustration right now also. That and people harassing and revenge downvoting me for expecting new people to do a reasonable amount of work before posting their question.

Comment: @jeffbRTC Delete *anything*. Does the code still crash? Great, delete something else. Does it not crash when you delete it? Then put it back and delete everything *except* that thing. Still doesn't crash? Then put everything back and try something else. When you're done, *every single line of code* should be something to do with the problem. And maybe you can spot the problem now. If not, then post the question.

Comment: @jeffbRTC For example: Why do you need this TLS::credentials class and globalCreds global variable, why can't you just do all the things inside `main`? You definitely don't need a namespace. And you have this vector `creds`, which you push to, but never access. Is that important for the problem? How about the expiry date and the hostname? Does it still crash if your cert doesn't have a hostname, doesn't have a country, if it expires after 0 seconds? It's not that these things are complicated, it's just that there are so many of them and *any one of them* might be part of the problem.

Answer (score 23):

Update: based on bolov's answer, the question in question was **far** from being minimal when it was posted.

I like the answer by Cody Gray but I thought I'd add some thoughts on how I perceive the question in question.

The question reads:

> **I'm using Botan to create a TLS application** and my application crash with a seg fault at end of the application.
>
> I made an attempt to debug this with Valgrind but it leading nowhere.
>
> Here is the stack trace from Valgrind,

... followed, essentially, by the code.

You said you created a **TLS application**. This is rather vague. A web browser is also a TLS application. I suggest rephrasing to, e.g.:

> I am trying to **generate a TLS certificate using Botan**.

This immediately narrows the scope of your question dramatically. With the original vague scope, someone may easily make a comment referencing MCVE while really meaning "please figure out what your problem is and clearly state it".

You then characterized your question as:

> It took me a lot of effort and energy to break down a multi threaded TLS application into a single threaded minimal application.
>
> I made sure that any one can build and run my minimal example without any frustrations. I included build instructions for this minimal application including the TLS library itself. I included the stack traces in addition to that.
>
> I've located the line which is causing the bug but I can't wrap my mind around how to go ahead and fix it, so I asked the question.

So, you created a *complete* and *verifiable* example, but is it *minimal*?

Let's say I, as a potential answerer, figured out that your question is about TLS certificate generation. Looking at the first page of your code I see includes for TLS server and session manager besides a ton of others. Maybe all of the pkcs and x509 stuff is really needed, but TLS manager? I suspect this code isn't *minimal*.

In the event that it *is*, and all of the includes are indeed required, you can reassure the readers that they aren't wasting their time by saying, e.g.:

> I reduced my application as much as I could and this is the smallest  application that shows the crash.

A statement like this would help *if* the rest of the post is consistent with it. Simply saying "I tried everything", when no work is shown, generally doesn't fool anyone. For questions that might appear borderline to someone, adding a bit of humanity can make the difference.

Separately, *minimal* example doesn't just refer to the number of lines of code, but also to the complexity and unusualness of what you are doing. Is storing your credentials globally *minimal*? You've found out that globals in C++ have non-trivial behavior attached to them. C++ experts know this. Upon seeing an application that stores classes globally they might think, "why don't you keep everything locally in main and see what happens"?

Let's say you didn't know about the globals' behavior, so to you it isn't obvious that the global version isn't actually minimal. **Follow the published documentation as closely as possible in your MCVE.** Whatever the documentation shows as working usage is likely the most tested, customary and likely to work usage. If you can't find any documentation, **say so in the question**. If you deviated from the documentation, **say so in the question and provide your reason** (you've done this in an update, I assume based on someone's comment).

Last but not least, it takes viewers time and effort to comment on your question and flag it. *Thinking* about how to flag it and comment on it in the most productive way possible **also takes time and effort**. And the SO UI isn't the most convenient to use, for some operations more so than others. Keep this in mind if the comment or flag seems like it isn't the optimal one.

To summarize:

- Clearly and specifically identify your problem to yourself.
- Clearly state the problem.
- State what you've done to troubleshoot.
- Describe all of the above and what your MCVE does **in words**.
- Make your MCVE not just as small but also as simple and as close to published documentation as possible.
- State what you have tried that *does* work.

Comment: I agree with "even a basic acknowledgment that you are following the rules would often make a difference" for this case of MCVE-making. However, I want to agree by pointing out the painful exception "I did search the net, but there is no answer to my question; honest." without any discussing of finds. I read that as "Honest, teacher. The dog eated my homeworks." and usually end up in a less helpful mood than without that...

Comment: You're right on that, I updated the answer to be hopefully more accurate.

Comment: Nice, I like it in its generalised way. Less case specific than my comment.